# Router login page open up automatically when I connected to the network

Tags: router

I'm using Router Tenda W309R http://www.tendacn.com/in/product/W309R.html

Every time I restarted the router, as soon as I connected back to the network a web browser on my computer opened up automatically to 192.168.80.1/index.asp

This is a router login page that came up when I connected to the network:

[image]

I have Mcafee Antivirus + Firewall installed on my PC. I have run full scan and no malware came up. I ran MalwareBytes Anti-Malware found only OpenCandy Ad-Ware which has nothing to do with the router

> Malwarebytes Anti-Malware www.malwarebytes.org
>
> Scan Date: 7/02/2016 Scan Time: 6:42 PM Logfile:  Administrator: Yes
>
> Version: 2.2.0.1024 Malware Database: v2016.02.07.01 Rootkit Database:
>   v2016.01.20.01 License: Free Malware Protection: Disabled Malicious
>   Website Protection: Disabled Self-protection: Disabled
>
> OS: Windows 8.1 CPU: x64 File System: NTFS User: E5
>
> Scan Type: Threat Scan Result: Completed Objects Scanned: 395511 Time
>   Elapsed: 5 min, 3 sec
>
> Memory: Enabled Startup: Enabled Filesystem: Enabled Archives: Enabled
>   Rootkits: Disabled Heuristics: Enabled PUP: Enabled PUM: Enabled
>
> Processes: 0 (No malicious items detected)
>
> Modules: 0 (No malicious items detected)
>
> Registry Keys: 0 (No malicious items detected)
>
> Registry Values: 0 (No malicious items detected)
>
> Registry Data: 0 (No malicious items detected)
>
> Folders: 0 (No malicious items detected)
>
> Files: 2 PUP.Optional.OpenCandy,
>   C:\Users\E5\AppData\Local\Temp\is-QKG4I.tmp\OCSetupHlp.dll, ,
>   [697470ed0693ef47cc404aa5f1135aa6],  PUP.Optional.OpenCandy,
>   C:\Users\Public\Downloads\AxCrypt-1.7.3156.0-Setup.exe, ,
>   [49947edf188137fffb11a7487b8917e9],
>
> Physical Sectors: 0 (No malicious items detected)
>
> (end)

How does this work? How can a router issued command to my computer to open a web browser and open a web page? Could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Did you install any software that came with the router? To be honest, any software *could* be doing this, it's hard to say for certain.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Jonno. No I didn't install any software from Tenda. I configured it using web interface only.

Comment: What happens if you don't login? Does the internet still work?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the WAN & LAN settings?

Comment: The Internet will work, I don't need to login to the router. Normally I just close the browser and It will never come up until I restart the router.

Comment: This router is a secondary router, it sits inside another network (I don't have access to the main Router/Gateway so I can't tell the whole configuration).
The main network is 192.168.1.0/24 with 192.168.1.254 Is the main Router/Gateway, DNS, DHCP.
This secondary router gets dynamic IP from main router DHCP and create another network 192.168.80.0/24 then assign itself as Gateway, DNS, DHCP for this network and forward traffic to 192.168.1.254

Answer (score 2):

After analyzed traffic with WireShark I finally found what was going on. It was WPAD(Web Proxy Autodiscovery Protocol) and NCSI(Network Connectivity Status Indicator) that opened up my web browser and redirect to router login page.

After reset the router and rejoined the network, my computer sent GET request for /wpad.dat to 192.168.80.1 and got this

```
GET /wpad.dat HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: WinHttp-Autoproxy-Service/5.1
Host: wpad.tenda.lan

HTTP/1.0 302 Redirect
Server: GoAhead-Webs
Date: Thu Jan 01 00:00:02 1970
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://wpad.tenda.lan/login.asp

<html><head></head><body>
This document has moved to a new <a href="http://wpad.tenda.lan/login.asp">location</a>.
Please update your documents to reflect the new location.
</body></html>
```

Then I searched about WPAD a little bit more and found out that I can disable from **Control Panel** -> **Internet Options** -> **Connections Tab** -> **LAN settings** -> **Automatically detect settings**

I disabled Automatically detect settings but the router login page still came up. I captured traffic again and found another GET request for /ncsi.txt sent to 192.168.80.1

```
GET /ncsi.txt HTTP/1.1
Connection: Close
User-Agent: Microsoft NCSI
Host: www.msftncsi.com

HTTP/1.0 302 Redirect
Server: GoAhead-Webs
Date: Thu Jan 01 00:00:01 1970
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://www.msftncsi.com/login.asp

<html><head></head><body>
This document has moved to a new <a href="http://www.msftncsi.com/login.asp">location</a>.
Please update your documents to reflect the new location.
</body></html>
```

This one seems to be used for connectivity check and get some network info. This can be disabled using regedit.exe and change DWORD Value of **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\EnableActiveProbing** from **1** to **0**

After I disabled both features the router login page is no longer came up automatically.

References:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713344.aspx
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766017%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Hi, if you’re still around, please accept this answer. The root cause would be that your router’s DNS service is malfunctioning. If it didn’t return itself for those queries, nothing would’ve happened.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many methods but it didn't work for me. There are some websites when i try to open it, it redirects me to my router home page. I did a little research and then i changed "http" to "https" and try to open those websites and that's it. My problem is solved. Now those websites doesn't redirect me to my router page and works fine.