# WPAD (Web Proxy Autodiscovery Protocol) can be used to automatically show a specific Webpage on all local network devices

Tags: wireless-networking, router, proxy, webserver

I don`t know this can be implemented or not can I use WPAD to open a website that is saved on my laptop automatically all local users connected to same network .
I want this page to be pushed automatically on all network connected devices so all users can get that page opens up as they connect to a network

for reference I found this below post 
But need exper guidance

[Router login page open up automatically when I connected to the network](https://superuser.com/questions/1036663/router-login-page-open-up-automatically-when-i-connected-to-the-network)

Answer (score 0):

Although `WPAD`-based solution might work, it is not ultimate: if a browser does not support `WPAD` or set to ignore `WPAD` then it won't be redirected to your landing page.

The proper solution would be to set at your router a firewall rule (or set of rules) to redirect the outside targeted tcp traffic to your web server.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more regarding this TCP firewall rule .

Comment: it depends on the router, see the accompanying documentation. If it were a router built on linux box, then the iptables rule would be 'iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d ! 192.168.0.0/16 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80' provided the intranet addresses are in 192.168.0.0/16 subnet and the router connected to the intranet with eth0 interface